# Laravel 5.6 | Eloquent One to Many Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm learning php and laravel. I'm doing a crud test for a company and if I pass I can be considered for joining the dev team. One of the requirements of the crud test is that a member (who is the main object) may have one language from a list of multiple language options. Obviously one language can be linked to multiple members.

So if I read laravel docs correctly, the foreign key between the main model (Member) and the secondary model (Language) will be setup automatically. My question is how to setup the relationship logically.

One of the columns in my members table is a language_id column and the languages table consist of id (obviously) and the name of the language.

According to examples the relationship should look something like this:

Member Model:

```
class Member extends Model 
{ 
   public function language() 
   { 
      return $this->hasMany('App\Language'); 
   } 
}
```

Language Model:

```
class Language extends Model 
{ 
   public function member() 
   { 
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Member'); 
   } 
}
```

But does this make sense? The Member model is essentially saying the member can have multiple languages. But that is not the case. The member can only have 1 language.

Can you please help me clarify this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `Language` be the one that `hasMany` members? And then a member should only have 1 language

Comment: ^ The you have the relationships turned around. Language has many members and a member belongs to a language

Comment: It should be turned around and then you get the right relationship

Comment: Maybe the company is looking if you can work out the logic yourself and not rely on forums. As others have already said you have it the wrong way around, should be belongsTo on User model.

Comment: That's correct, I had my relation the wrong way around. TonySawlwin, it's my understanding that especially while learning coding it is good to rely on forums. It proves that you can go and figure things out and learn through forums. Our devs are open to that anyway. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Your relation is wrong.

Because a member can only has one language, a `Member` is `belongsTo` `Language`, not `hasMany` `Language`. Therefore, a `Language` will `hasMany` a lot of `Member`s.

See:

- Simple db:

**members**:

`id  | name     | language_id  |
int | var_char | int+nullable | // because member can have no lang`

**languages**

`id  | name     |
int | var_char |`

- Relation:

(2 files)

```
class Member extends Model 
{ 
   public function language() 
   { 
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Language', 'language_id'); 
   } 
}

class Language extends Model 
{ 
   public function members() 
   { 
      return $this->hasMany('App\Member', 'language_id'); 
   } 
}
```

The `language_id` is the foreign key for the relation. In this case, use this or not is not master.

Then, when you want to retrieve member language, just use `$member->language`; and, when you want to retrieve all members that have the `$language`, use `$language->members`

Hope this help!

Comment: This is correct. However, as you mentioned, I don't have to specify the fk as laravel does that in the background.

Comment: Laravel will auto add the fk for you in cased that the fk format is `strtolower(<ModelName>).'_id'`. If you set fk name with other format, you need to set fk manually in Eloquent Relationship. Eg: if you use `lang_id` instead of `language_id`, you have to set `$this->belongsTo('App\Language', 'lang_id');` that `lang_id` is required.

Answer (score -1):

**you should create one junction model MemberLanguage (obviously this will have a table with member_id and language_id attribute) where you will have member_id and language_id, so the relation in Member model u can have is-**

```
class Member extends Model
 { 
     public function memberLanguage()
      {
         return $this->hasMany('App\MemberLanguage');
      } 
   }
```

**In your MemberLanguage Model, you will have**

```
class MemberLanguage extends Model 
{ 
   public function member() 
   { 
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Member'); 
   } 

   public function language() 
   { 
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Language'); 
   } 
}
```